# How to select dynamically value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a value that is added dynamically to element. So my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="some_class value0">
  <div>
    100,00 €
  </div>
</div>
```

This `value0` can be any number, like `value150` or `value201` basically any number from `0 - ∞`.

So my question is how can I select this value with jQuery?

Can I do it like this:

```
var select = $('.value[^=]');
```

Comment: You can get all elements using `$('[class*="value"]')`

Answer (score 2):

If you can move the value class to the beginning in your html, then you can use the [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
jQuery("[class^='value']")
```

Otherwise you will have to use the [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
jQuery("[class*='value']")
```

However, this could include things with a class such as `no-value` or anything else that has `value` anywhere in it's class

A preferable option would be to just give all those items a common class and use that instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) a selector.

```
var all_selected = $('[class^="value"]')
```

This will give you all the elements having class starting with "value". Then you can loop through and get the value of each element.

Answer (score 0):

I see from the question that you want to select values with the class like ".value1,.value2,.value123" and so on. So why don't you select the values by the second class name you specified?

Like 
var selectedDomData = $('.some_class').text();

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an element like this:

```
<div class="some_class value" id="value0">
  <div>
    100,00 €
  </div>
</div>
```

Select all value classes with:

```
const values = document.querySelectorAll(".value")
```

And now you can select each individual value from the id:

```
values.forEach(value => console.log(value.id))
```